# Angular ui-select options showing behind the modal when used with Bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-select

I am facing issue with Angular `ui-select` (replacement for HTML select). I have added the option `append-to-body` so that it can be shown on top of other elements.

But I am facing an issue that when it is used on top of bootstrap modal, it does not show list of options. In fact it shows the list of options are displayed behind the modal, as you can see in the image.

Is there any workaround that issue?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Simply add a `z-index` CSS property greater than 1050 for the parent element of the `ui-select` element.

**Why greater than 1050?**

Because the `z-index` on the `.modal` class is set to `1050` so we need to provide higher `z-index` of the parent element of the dropdown so that it can appear above the modal in z-axis.

Comment: hello  I am using a wrapper around ui-select, so the z-index property is added to all the ui-select components, in my application, i just realized that this is causing a side affect. Now when i open up any modal popup, it is showing the comboboxes on top of the modal, which are on the page. any solution for this?

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr/fiddle or SO snippet for the same?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and in my case I was using `append-to-body="true"` in my `ui-select` directive. Setting this to false fixed it for me.